# nutch2.0 with cassandra

Tags: eclipse, cassandra, nutch, gora

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:214)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:68)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:136)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:257)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraStore.initialize(CassandraStore.java:88)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraMapping.<init>(CassandraMapping.java:117)
    at org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraMappingManager.get(CassandraMappingManager.java:84)
    at org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraClient.initialize(CassandraClient.java:84)
    at org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraStore.initialize(CassandraStore.java:85)
    ... 10 more
```

**I just run nutch2.0 on cassandra. It's the output of crawl, and the output of TestGoreStorage is as following:**

```
Starting!
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.TestGoraStorage.main(TestGoraStorage.java:204)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraStore.initialize(CassandraStore.java:88)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraMapping.<init>(CassandraMapping.java:117)
    at org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraMappingManager.get(CassandraMappingManager.java:84)
    at org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraClient.initialize(CassandraClient.java:84)
    at org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraStore.initialize(CassandraStore.java:85)
    ... 5 more
```

**I can connect cassandra with cassandra-cli, and just check out the nutch from svn.
Here is the effect config in gora.properties:**

```
    gora.datastore.default=org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraStore
    gora.sqlstore.jdbc.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
    gora.sqlstore.jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://210.44.138.8/nutchtest
    gora.sqlstore.jdbc.user=sa
    gora.sqlstore.jdbc.password=
    gora.cassandrastore.servers=210.44.138.8:9160
```

**and the config in gora-cassandra-mapping:**

```
<keyspace name="webpage" cluster="My Cluster" host="210.44.138.8">
    <family name="p"/>
    <family name="f"/>
    <family name="sc" type="super"/>
</keyspace>
```

**210.44.138.8 is a node of my cluster, and the name of cluster is "My Cluster",
more info: closed firewall, run in eclipse. I'm very pleasure if someone give me any help.**

Comment: I think I'm running into the same problem.  Debugging now...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I had the exact same problem, but I found that in the gora-cassandra-mapping.xml file I had to add a keyspace attribute (**keyspace="ks1"**) to the class element:

```
<keyspace name="ks1" cluster="My Cluster" host="1.2.3.4">
    ...
</keyspace>
<class keyspace="ks1" keyClass="java.lang.String" name="org.apache.nutch.storage.WebPage">
    ...
</class>
```

Comment: Now I change database to HBase, and it works today. But the hbase and zookeeper made a lot of chaos to me, and I hope I can finish the deploynent with hadoop before Mid-autumn festival.